# OR symbol between two regular expressions

Tags: sql, regex, select

I need to extract words between `FROM` and `WHERE` or `;`

For this I had

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\bFROM\\b).*?(?=\\bWHERE\\b)");
```

This is working fine.

Example 1:

```
input = "select * from emp, dept where 1 =1 "
```

Using above pattern it will return as

```
emp, dept
```

Example 2:

```
input = "select * from emp, dept"
```

From the above input I wrote like below:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\bFROM\\b).*?(?=\\bWHERE|;\\b)");
```

to return `emp,dept`, but it's not returning that.

Will you please help us to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using regexps to parse HTML?

Comment: Consider this: `SELECT column_FROM FROM table_WHERE WHERE 1=1`

Comment: @Bart I think that `\b` is used for this purpose.. hence no problem.

Comment: @bluish, ah, yeah, many regex implementations do not "see" a `\b` between the `_` and `F` from my column name (but undoubtedly some do!). But that's not really my point: my point was (or is) that such a simple test may very well fail in certain SQL statements. Consider this one: `SELECT \`foo FROM bar\` FROM \`x WHERE y\` WHERE 1=1`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your expression to recognize all the characters in the WHERE clause, and make it optional

```
(?<=\bFROM\b).*?(\s*WHERE\s.*)?$
```

Comment: If you have `"select * from emp, dept order by id"` it will match a wrong substring.